# Numbers to stop at the user's input

Tags: java

How do I make my program to stop at the user's input?
Here is my code:

```
public class H {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input x: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (i < x)
                System.out.print(printFib(i) + " ");
            else if (i > x)
                break;
        }
    }

    public static int printFib(int number) {
        if (number == 0 || number == 1)
            return number;
        else
            return printFib(number - 1) + printFib(number - 2);
    }
}
```

So, if I enter 10 my program should stop before the number. Example:

Input: 10

Output: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8

But instead I get 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

How can I fix it?

```
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int fib = 0;    
        while (fib < x){


    System.out.print(printFib(fib)+ " ");
       fib++;


    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you need to compare the value returned by `printFib` with your "termination" value and exit the loop when they agree

Comment: There's no purpose to your `if-else` block in the loop. `i` will always be smaller than `x` inside the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class H {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input x: ");
    int x = input.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    while ( printFib(i) <= x ) {
        System.out.print(printFib(i) + " "); 
        i ++ ;
    }
}

public static int printFib(int number) {
    if (number == 0 || number == 1)
        return number;
    else
        return printFib(number - 1) + printFib(number - 2);
}

}
```

While the number return from the `printFib()` method is less than and equal to the user input, it then runs the method. I've tried the code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a **for** loop which right now you're using to print out Fibonacci numbers until the number of items printed is less than the entered number. Instead use a **while** loop that stops when the Fibonacci number itself is greater than the entered number.

Since this is likely homework, I'm just going to give this suggestion and not a code solution, but please give a solution a try, and if still stuck, come back with questions.

Pseudocode

```
Get value of x
create fibonacci variable and assign it 0
while fibonacci is less than x
   display current fibonacci number
   calculate next fibonacci number and place in variable
end while loop
```

Comment: I gave it a try and got stuck with an infinite loop. Any hint?

Comment: @AndrewSchertwegger: not without code. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32706979/edit) your question by clicking on the link. Leave your original code in place, and add changes to the bottom as well as effect. Likely your while condition is off.

Comment: Sorry if I am rusty in java it's been a while and I'm trying my best. I did the while loop, got the same output as before

Comment: @AndrewSchertwegger: why the `while (true)`? that's not at all what I recommended. You should check the actual Fibonacci number with x within the while loop's condition and nothing else. Also, `i` is being used as a loop index and shouldn't be tested in the while condition, just the Fibonacci number.

Comment: something like while(i <= x)?

Comment: @AndrewSchertwegger: No -- again, `i` has no business within the while condition. You **test the Fibonacci number**. Don't just print it out -- put it in a variable and test it.

Comment: @AndrewSchertwegger: check pseudocode above. No breaks, no ifs, just short a while loop.

Comment: I did the pseudocode. Hopefully I did it right. And it's shorter than my old loop.

Comment: @AndrewSchertwegger: No, you just renamed `i` fib. Changing a variable name without changing anything else will change nothing.